# Examples of rings that are Noetherian but not finitely generated?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, modules, noetherian

> [image]

---

**Is there something missing from the highlighted statement?**

From my understanding, if a ring is Noetherian, then it is finitely generated.

Comment: Well, take any field extension of your base field which is not finitely generated. It is certainly Noetherian. For instance $\mathbb{C}/\mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: The parenthetical comment in the highlighted passage should suggest some constructions.  Note that the context seems to be that $S$ is an $R$-algebra which is a Noetherian ring but not finitely generated as an $R$-algebra.

Comment: Please add a citation of the book from which this exercise is taken.  It would be preferable to use $\LaTeX$ and [MathJax](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation) to present the problem, rather than posting an image, but if necessary to do it this way, the book's author and title are still important.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The misunderstanding is about the usage of “finitely generated”.

The part you emphasized is about Noetherian rings which are algebras over a field, but are not finitely generated *as algebras*.

An algebra $R$ over a field $F$ is finitely generated *as an algebra* if (and only if) there exists a surjective $F$-algebra homomorphism $F[X_1,X_2,\dots,X_n]\to R$, for some $n$. Since the domain is Noetherian, the codomain is Noetherian as well.

On the other hand, an $F$-algebra can be Noetherian without being finitely generated as an algebra: take the algebraic closure of a finite field, for instance, or $\mathbb{C}$ as an algebra over $\mathbb{Q}$.

An example related to the comment in the quoted text is the localization $\mathbb{Z}_{(p)}$ at a prime $p$. This is a Noetherian ring, but it is not finitely generated, because there are infinitely many primes.

Comment: What does it mean for $R$-algebra, $S$, to be Noetherian? Noetherian as a ring, or Noetherian as an $R$-module?

Comment: @AlJebr Noetherian as ring

Answer (score 9):

If $R$ is commutative and noetherian, then $R[[X]]$ too. But $R[[X]]$ is not finitely generated.

Comment: but is it finitely generated because it has the identity element?

Comment: @permutation_matrix I don't understand your question. Any group / ring has an identity element, this has nothing to do with being finitely generated

Comment: since it has an identity element, then it is generated by the identity element so it is finitely generated. But you are saying it is not finitely generated

Comment: @permutation_matrix No it isn't, the identity element only generates a subring isomorphic to the integers

Comment: Or to $\Bbb Z / n \Bbb Z$ if $R$ has torsion